# React: sass-loader not transpiling SCSS into CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, mdbreact

I have a `react` app with `CSS` files working fine.
I need to start using `SCSS` so the following changes:

1. Install `node-sass` and `sass-loader`
2. Change the imports from `.css` to `.scss`
3. Change file extension from `.css` to `.scss`

But my pages are not loading properly:

Current behavior: [image]

Expected behavior: [image]

My code:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^3.0.0",
    "@stardust-ui/docs-components": "^0.40.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "compass": "^0.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "mdbreact": "^4.25.4",
    "prettier": "^1.6.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-bootstrap-sidebar": "0.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-fixed-bottom": "^1.0.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.1",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "reconnecting-websocket": "^4.2.0",
    "reconnectingwebsocket": "^1.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

I injected the code for the loaders in node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js like this:

```
// Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              // @remove-on-eject-begin
              babelrc: false,
              presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
              // @remove-on-eject-end
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
          { 
            test: /\.scss$/, 
            loader: [
              "css-loader",
              "sass-loader"
            ]
          },
```

Here is my component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import '../../../general.scss';
import { Warning } from '../../../images/images_svg';

class Terminos extends Component{
  state = { error: false }

  saveAndContinue = () => {
    if(this.props.values.terminos) {
       this.props.nextStep()      
    }
    else {
       console.log(this.props.values.terminos_error)
       this.props.mandar_error('terminos_error')
    }     
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div className="formulario">
        <div className="formulario-seccion-titulo">
          <div className="formulario-seccion-barrita"/>
            <div className="formulario-seccion-content">
               Presentacion
            </div>
          </div>      
          <div className={this.props.values.terminos_error ? "formulario-seccion" : "formulario-seccion-red"}>
             La actual pandemia que afecta al mundo trae consecuencias a nivel sanitario, económico y social. Lo que está ocurriendo con el COVID impacta de lleno, no sólo en la salud física de las personas, sino que también afecta de forma clara y contundente su salud mental.<br/><br/>
             Ud. puede decidir si contestar o no la encuesta que sigue pero de hacerlo,acepta que los resultados de la misma sean compartidos con su empleador con el único fin de brindarle contención y asistencia. La encuesta debe completarse en las próximas 10 horas.<br/><br/>
             <input type="checkbox" 
               id="terminos" 
               className="formulario-checkbox"
               onChange={() => this.props.handleTerminos()}
               checked={this.props.values.terminos}
             />  
             <label className="formulario-checkbox-label" htmlFor="terminos"> 
               Acepto terminos y condiciones.
             </label>
             {this.props.values.terminos_error===false &&
                <div className="formulario-seccion-error">
                  <div className="formulario-seccion-error-logo" >
                    <Warning color="#d93025"/>
                  </div>
                    Debes aceptar los terminos y condiciones para continuar
                </div>
              }
           </div>
           <div className="formulario-footer">
             <button className="formulario-botones" onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Siguiente</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       )    
    }
}

export default Terminos;
```

If I change the import and the file extension from `.scss` to `.css` the page load properly.
I´m using `npm start` to develop and testing the code.

Comment: Are there any errors returned that you could share as well?

Comment: No errores, console is clean. It is like the css in not there at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created project with Create-React-App?
In this case, you don't need **sass-loader**, you just need **node-sass**, and import your CSS style into your root file with .scss/sass extension, for example, `import '../example.scss'`, then need to configure webpack.config.js at all.

Please provide more information.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes, i have created the project with Create-React-App. I´m importing the scss files as you said (check the component code in the question). The path is correct as no erros are shown, and if I change the import and the file extension from .scss to .css the page load properly.

Comment: Do you use a third-party CSS framework or something jquery related?

Comment: In fact, am actually wondering, if you used `create-react-app` to kick-start your project then `Webpack` should already have been configured.

Comment: I used  `create-react-app`, then i created the webpack.config.js because i´m having this issue

Comment: Ok, so we are dealing with a deeper challenge. If you're still using `npm start` to launch your app, then I hope you are aware that it actually uses `react-scripts` which has a `Webpack config`. So unless you run `npm eject`, I believe your own `Webpack config` isn't being read at all by `react`. It explains why `.css` is loaded while `.scss` isn't. We now need to address if your introduced `node-sass` and `sass-loader` the right way. For one, having worked with `SCSS`, am aware that there's a lot of version issues as concerns `node-sass`. Did you get any warning at installation?

Comment: I think we are on the right track here. I added sccs in the extension line: `extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx','scss'],` and this in the rules line: `{ 
            test: /\.scss$/, 
            loader: [
              "css-loader",
              "sass-loader"
            ]
          },`. Still not working, but if i uninstall sass-loader the command `npm start` fails with error code:
Module not found: Can't resolve 'sass-loader'

Comment: For a better review, kindly update your QUESTION with the latest changes. Including what has been updated in the `package.json` and within your `Webpack.config`.

Comment: ok, i updated my question with the lastest changes. Could it be that there is something wrong with the way i introduced the loaders in the webpack.config.dev.js

Answer (score 0):

> `Webpack` has seen tremendous changes up until `version 4`

When we use `create-react-app`, it installs a compatible version of `Webpack` that `react-scripts` utilizes to bundle your files and serves them using `Webpack-server` as the dev server when you run `npm start`.

- Remove `"webpack": "^3.11.0"` from your `package.json`
  since it's already installed by `react-scripts`.
- Also `react 16+` often works with `react-scripts 3+` so if you manually edited some of this `package.json` file, i recommend you leave the defaults installed by `create-react-app` and just add your other `dependencies`.

Otherwise, here's [What Webpack says about loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/).

Comment: Ok, i modify the webpack config, the result is the same, thx anyway

Comment: Please see my updated answer to this issue. If you stick to the approach of `create-react-app`, just installing `node-sass` and `sass-loader` should be enough for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it deleting the node-modules folder, the package-lock.json and all my dependencies in the package.json. Then I reinstalled all my dependencies with `npm install ...`. I think the problem was the react-scripts module, i upgraded from version 1.1.5 to 3.4.1 . Thank you all for your answers.